# I sold my old iPhone and it says “offline” will texts messages still show up in it?

Tags: iphone, messages, settings, find-my-iphone, messages-in-icloud

I sold my old iPhone to my boyfriends ex girlfriend, I think I went in settings and reset all content and settings. 
Will my old texts still be on it? And could it still be receiving my text and iMessages?
On “find my iPhone” the device is on the list, but it says “offline” does that mean I didn’t wipe it correctly and all my old texts and pictures and everything are still on it for her to go through?

Comment: did you disconnect it from iCloud/iTunes

Comment: Maybe you should have made sure you cleared it before selling it, but in any event, I would suggest asking her if she is receiving texts.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I’m not sure if I did or not. How would I do that? And we don’t talk at all so asking her isn’t really an option. When I go to iCloud.com it’s no longer listed under my devices, but when I go to find my iPhone it’s listed on there but is “offline” should I just “remove device”? My laptop is broken so I can’t use it to go on my actual iTunes account.

Comment: yes remove it ....

Answer (score 1):

Change your AppleID/iCloud password, that way if the account is still on the device it would ask for a password and become disabled.